# How can I change the color of Brave tabs to be higher contrast?

Tags: brave

I'm using Brave Version 1.16.72 Chromium: 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

If I have multiple tabs open in Private mode, the tabs look like this, which is great:

[image]

But if I then click my mouse over into a program other than Brave, the Brave tabs slightly change color, making the "current" tab barely distinguishable from the rest:

[image]

**How can I make it more obvious which tab is currently showing in Brave Private mode when a program other than Brave has focus?**